# Showing folder contents in html page?

Tags: php, html, css, apache

Im working on a section of my site which is for file storage. By default when you navigate to a folder without index.html all the files and directories are listed, and can be downloaded. I was wondering how I could keep this but style the page and add extra links and buttons to it. Thanks

Comment: So its okay for people to see contents of every folder that does not contain a `index.html`? The things people can do with that....(and I'm not talking about good things either)

Comment: I recommend you read: http://www.redips.net/apache/styling-directory-listings/ and http://paradox460.newsvine.com/_news/2008/04/05/1413490-how2-stylish-apache-directory-listings which are the of searching `styling apache directory listings` in google

Comment: @navnav Nah all of them are blocked off except for a select few which require passwords so Im all good there =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is generated by [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

You can use the [HeaderName directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername) to insert a file into the top of the response (including some content and `<link>`s to stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in a quick search, but haven't messed with it before:

http://paradox460.newsvine.com/_news/2008/04/05/1413490-how2-stylish-apache-directory-listings